# Android - Drop down menus

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu

I'm searching about a kind of drop down menus like wikipedia mobile ones:

[image]

[image]

The problem is that I don't find the correct widget, I just find Spinners and there are not exactly what I want.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you have to use expandable listview
Tutorial Link - http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Android developers link - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: That is exactly what I was searching. Thanks !!